# Starting Index of a Sequence of Consecutive Numbers Sum Equals to Target Value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

How can I find the starting index of a sequence of consecutive numbers whose sum is equal to the target value? I absolutely have no idea, so I couldn't write a line of code.

For example, input: `([0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8, 6], 7)`. Output: 3 because `[5, 1, 1]` starts at index 3.

Comment: You could use `join`? And then use `indexOf` to find the index? --- What does `, 7)` mean? How does it relate to the input or output?

Comment: one example: `[0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8, 6].join('').indexOf(5, 1, 1].join(''))` outputs `3`

Comment: 7 is the target value in the example input. This is a kind of algorithm question, so we do not know the input values.

Comment: @TToprak1 Is there a specific time complexity you are expected to achieve?

Comment: Well, O(n) should be acceptable.

Comment: 5+1+1 = 7. These consecutive numbers sum equal to the target value. There is no other CONSECUTIVE numbers sum equal to the target value in the example.

Comment: Right, I do see that. What have you tried so far? It would be good to see how you've already tried to solve the problem. (no matter how "bad" it is)

Comment: Yes, it would be great If I was able to write anything.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: It seems you're misreading the problem.  The `7` is the target sum for the total of a contiguous subArray.  `[5, 1, 1]` just happens to be the first contiguous subarray  with that total, but it might be `[3, 1, 2, 1]` or `[7]` instead.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I did misunderstand. Thankfully it was clarified for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a sliding window to solve this problem with `O(N)` time complexity.

```js
function getStart(arr, sum){
  let left = 0, right = 0, current = 0;
  while(left < arr.length){
    while(right < arr.length && current < sum) 
      current += arr[right++];
    if(current === sum) return left;
    if(left < right) current -= arr[left++];
  }
  return -1;
}
console.log(getStart([0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8, 6], 7));
```

Comment: We should note that this will only be guaranteed if the numbers are all positive (or non-negative?).  For instance `getStart([0, 3, 5, -1, 6], 7)` yields `-1`, even though `3 + 5 + (-1)` is `7`.